# Win32 Thread scheduling

Tags: winapi

As I understand, windows thread scheduler does not discriminate beween threads belonging two different processes, provided all of them have the same base priority. My question is if I have two applications one with only one thread and the other with say 50 threads all with same base priority, does it mean that the second process enjoys more CPU time then the first one?

Comment: And what if one application has 50 processes and the other only has one. Should the first application get more CPU time?

Answer (score 10):

Scheduling in Windows is at the **thread granularity**. The basic idea behind this approach is that processes don't run but only provide resources and a context in which their threads run. Coming back to your question, because scheduling decisions are made strictly on a thread basis, no consideration is given to what process the thread belongs to. In your  example, if process A has 1 runnable thread and process B has 50 runnable threads, and all 51 threads are at the same priority, each thread would receive 1/51 of the CPU time—**Windows wouldn't give 50 percent of the CPU to process A and 50 percent to process B**.
To understand the thread-scheduling algorithms, you must first understand the priority levels that Windows uses. You can [refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685100(VS.85).aspx) here for quick reference.

Try reading [Windows Internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) for in depth understanding.

Comment: Info is also here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810029.aspx#irql_sched_topic5

Comment: So it's fair to say that Window thread scheduler uses a 'fair' algorithm e.g. all threads with the same priority level are equally likely to be scheduled? If so, for same priority level threads, which one is scheduled first? Is the order random or is it deterministic in some way?

Answer (score 5):

All of the above are accurate but if you're worried about the 50 thread process hogging all the CPU, there ARE techniques you can do to ensure that no single process overwhelms the CPU.

IMHO the best way to do this is to use [job objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161.aspx) to manage the usage of a process.  First call [CreateJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682409(VS.85).aspx), then [SetInformationJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686216(VS.85).aspx) to limit the max CPU usage of the processes in the job object and [AssignProcessToJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681949(VS.85).aspx) to assign the process with 50 threads to the job object.  You can then let the OS ensure that the 50 thread process doesn't consume too much CPU time.

Comment: If there were tools for this usable by end-users, that would be a huge win for Windows.

Comment: There are, sort-of. Start task manager, right click on a process and select "Set affinity".  This allows you to assign individual threads to specific CPUs.  It's not quite the same thing but it's close.

Answer (score 3):

The unit of scheduling is a thread, not a process, so a process with 50 threads, all in a tight loop, will get much more of the cpu than a process with only a single thread, provided all are running at the same priority.  This is normally not a concern since most threads in the system are not in a runnable state and will not be up for scheduling; they are waiting on I/O, waiting for input from the user, and so on.

Windows Internals is a great book for learning more about the Windows thread scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the behavior of the threads.  In general with a 50 : 1 difference in thread count, yes, the application with more threads is going to get a lot more time.  However, windows also uses dynamic thread prioritization, which can change this somewhat.  Dynamic thread prioritization is described here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130312225716/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109228

Relevant excerpt:

> The base priority of a thread is the base level from which these upward adjustments are made. The current priority of a thread is called its dynamic priority. Interactive threads that yield before their time slice is up will tend to be adjusted upward in priority from their base priority. Compute-bound threads that do not yield, consuming their entire time slice, will tend to have their priority decreased, but not below the base level. This arrangement is often called heuristic scheduling. It provides better interactive performance and tends to lessen the system impact of "CPU hog" threads.

Answer (score 0):

There is a local 'advanced' setting that purportedly can be used to shade scheduling slightly in favor of the app with focus.   With the 'services' setting, there is no preference.   In previous versions of Windows, this setting used to be somewhat more granular than just 'applications with focus'(slight preference to app with focus) and 'services' (all equal weigthing)

As this can be set by the user on the targe machine, it seems like it is asking for grief to depend on this setting...